# Is it possible to prevent a macro from hiding a function?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

For legacy reasons, I have a macro; call it `#define foo`. Now, `foo` is a non-function-type macro. I need for `foo` to expand to either nothing, or something which can be ignored by the compiler (e.g. an attribute) when it precedes a function call.

However, I find that I now also need to create a function named `foo`.

The preprocessor treats function-style macros different from non-function macros, which implies there *might* be a way to get it to transform `foo(...)` differently from, say, `foo ...`. However, I can't just give a different definition to `foo` as a function-macro.

Is there any way I can solve this problem?

p.s. "Don't do that in the first place" is not helpful. The `foo` macro already exists; it is ***not*** feasible to change it, nor the newly introduced function (which is outside of my control). Please limit discussion to *answering the question as asked*.

---

Example:

```cpp
#define /* ... magic here ... */

  // void foo(int x, int y); <-- might be in a module

  void bar()
  {
    // First 'foo' has no effect
    // Second 'foo' calls the function 'foo'
    foo foo(42, 7);
  }
```

Comment: I would just suggest using find and replace

Comment: @Asadefa, not plausible. This problem exists in a *widely* used library; literally *thousands* of projects would need to be changed. And the conflicting function is actually not under my control either.

Comment: So you are managing a widely used library?

Comment: Can't you `#undef foo` if it's defined?

Comment: Give the function some other name than `foo`.

Comment: @vahancho, no, because then every user of the symbolic form of `foo` breaks.

Comment: Can you give a real-code example of what you want to do?

Comment: Could you work with `#pragma push_macro(foo)`, `#undef foo` ... `#pragma pop_macro(foo)`?

Comment: @dfri, it's ugly, but actually that *is* another possibility that I hadn't thought of if someone needs to call `foo`. (There is actually also a "don't define `foo` hook, but using it tends to somewhat uglify code.)

Comment: @Matthew: "*I didn't create this situation*" Didn't you? You state that you need to create a function with the same name as a macro. So unless some external code is *forcing you* to use a specific function name (which may be the case), you have the freedom to use a different name. And if that is the case, then you should state this up-front in your question.

Comment: @NicolBolas, that *is* the case. (Although one reason I would like to *also* create a function is because it might help migrate away from a `foo` macro. Unfortunately, any name other than `foo` — obviously I'm not using the real name here — as the function name would be abstruse. But the problem arose because an external library — C++ itself, in fact — decided to introduce a function with the same name as a widely used macro.)

Comment: @Matthew: You should put that information in your question. You should also say whether the conflict is due to the same library that defined the macro or a different one.

Comment: @NicolBolas, the reason I'm asking the question should not matter. It is a technical, "is there any way to accomplish this?" question. If people can't answer a technical question without knowing why I am asking, IMO there is something wrong. Anyway, read the "p.p.s.".

Comment: @Matthew: "*the reason I'm asking the question should not matter*" It does matter. Remember: SO is a site for all skill levels, so we see a lot of stupid stuff. It would not be the silliest question on the site if the only reason for this conflict were that the poster really liked the name `foo` and just wanted to use it, rather than having a need imposed on them by the outside. A problem created through a user's bad choices is a bad question, and that could explain some of the downvoting.

Comment: Again, "it is not feasible to change the symbolic macro, nor the newly introduced function". It's already there.

Comment: @Matthew, I'd say toning down the question would help. I did downvote, because I felt the bold uppercase directives on what to not answer did not make for a great question.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to have a name *contextually* be a macro. Either it is some `#define` or it is not.

This is a **major** reason why macros should be avoided or have `SHOUTY` names.

Comment: Technically, this is wrong; a function-like macro is only a macro if used in a function-like manner. Anyway, I was thinking more along the lines of abusing substitution limits, but the trick is getting `foo` and `foo(...)` to somehow lead to *different* substitution chains.

Comment: There is (foo).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow that prevents function-like macros from expanding, but won't stop a regular macro.

Comment: That was about "contextually be a macro". foo(...) and (foo)(...) behave different, only the first expands a function-like macro `#define foo(x) ...`. Not sure if you can do anything with that to get  different substitution chains.

Comment: You *can* have `#define foo(...) (__VA_ARGS__)`, which allows you to *declare* `void foo foo(int) {}`. But then you have `foo foo(1);` at the call site

Answer (score 1):

Before the macro declare foo function and define goo function

```
void foo();
inline void goo(){
    foo();
}
#define foo
```

You can call goo function, which will be inlined after macro expansion.

```
foo goo();
```

At the bottom of the file define foo, or declare as extern at the top and have in another file.

```
#undef foo
void foo(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to define foo and foo(...). But then you get:

```
foo.cc:2:0: warning: "foo" redefined
```

You can't define both.

You have to name the function something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent only a *function-like* macro from expanding. E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo() { return 2; }

#define foo() 1

int main() {
    std::cout << foo() << '\n';   // Outputs 1.
    std::cout << (foo)() << '\n'; // Outputs 2.
}
```